# IronWebScraper needing to login first before scraping

Tags: c#, web-scraping, session-cookies, setcookie

I am wanting to scrap a page (https://www.cdc.co.nz/products/list.html?cat=5201) that needed to be authenticated first (via this link https://www.cdc.co.nz/login/). After visiting multiple SO links, I have arrived to the code below.

So far, the code below has allowed me to login successfully. However, I suspect I have not transferred all the cookie information to IronWebScraper to the point it knows enough "authentication information" to scrap the desired page as I am getting the error message:

**ProductScraperFactory Critical, Http: Url failed permanently after 8 attempts: https://www.cdc.co.nz/products/list.html?cat=5201**.

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    HttpClientHandler handler;

    using (handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    })

    //Let's login first
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        string urlToPost = "https://www.cdc.co.nz/login/";

        HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent("username=USERNAME&password=hunter2");

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        //Yes this works - getting a 200 status code
        Task.Run(async () => response = await client.PostAsync(urlToPost, stringContent)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        var headerValues = response.Headers.ToList();

        HttpIdentity identity = new HttpIdentity {UseCookies = true};
        foreach (var headerKV in headerValues)
        {
            identity.HttpRequestHeaders.Add(headerKV.Key, headerKV.Value.ToArray()[0]);
        }

        Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.cdc.co.nz/login/");

        var cookieValue = headerValues.Where(c => c.Key == "Set-Cookie").Select(c => c).ToArray()[0].Value.ToArray()[0];

        identity.Cookies.SetCookies(uri, cookieValue);

        identity.Cookies.Add(cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri));

        identity.UserAgent =
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36";

        Request request = new Request {Identity = identity};

        //Let's see if we can see any Duracell
        var scraper = new ProductScraperFactory("https://www.cdc.co.nz/products/list.html?cat=5201", ScrapingOperation.CDC, request);
        scraper.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

My ProductScraperFactory, which is extended from IronWebScraper's WebScraper class:

```
    private Request _request;
public ProductScraperFactory(string URLToScrap, ScrapingOperation operation, Request request)
        {
            _scrapingOperation = operation;
            _urlToScrap = URLToScrap;

            ChooseIdentityForRequest(request);
            _request = request;
        }


        public override void Init()
        {
            Request(_urlToScrap, Parse, _request.Identity);
        }

        public override void Parse(Response response)
        { ...}
```

Doc on ChooseIdentityForRequest: https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/webscraper/help/html/2498dbf0-8d85-70bf-4d82-a748be9a3a51.htm

Doc on Request: https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/webscraper/help/html/f28b6dc8-939c-dd94-3534-bada24edc1fa.htm

Comment: Can you try moving this line `HttpIdentity identity = new HttpIdentity {UseCookies = true};`  to the top, and then do `var cookieContainer = identity.Cookies;` and remove all other juggling with cookies on that `identity` instance (`identity.Cookies.SetCookies` and `identity.Cookies.Add`). That should at least release you from the burden to parse responses for cookies and guarantees all the cookies are shared among calls

Comment: Also would I start with a simple GET on the root of that website (or a GET on that login page) with that cookiecontainer already hooked up before you attempt to post. That website creates a session when you do a get, the /login post route might expect a session exists and gets confused or assumes a rogue scraper when there is no session present.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can start with something simpler. Start with just signing in on the site in your web browser, then use the developer settings in the browser to get the session token. E.g.:

[image: finding session token in the browser]

Then in the scraper, add the session token like this:

```cs
class MyScraper : WebScraper
{
    public override void Init()
    {
        HttpRetryAttempts = 0;
        LoggingLevel = LogLevel.Critical;
        Identities.Add(new()
        {
            UseCookies = true,
        });
        Identities[0].Cookies.SetCookies(new("https://intranet.kvadrat.se/"), "ASP.NET_SessionId=aaegnlsqs3c1jjj5sqpwmuyl");
        Request($"https://intranet.kvadrat.se/SubPage.cshtml", Parse);
    }

    public override void Parse(Response response)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

By starting with something simpler like this, you can more easily discover if you have gotten the right cookie.